# image compression in php

Tags: php, image, file, class, compression

I am compressing an image using following class..

```
<?php
class SimpleImage {

var $image;
var $image_type;

function load($filename) {

  $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
  $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
  if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

     $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
  } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

     $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
  } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

     $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
  }
 }
 function save($filename,$image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG,$compression=75,$permissions=null){

  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
     imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

     imagegif($this->image,$filename);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

     imagepng($this->image,$filename);
  }
  if( $permissions != null) {

     chmod($filename,$permissions);
  }
}
function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
     imagejpeg($this->image);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

     imagegif($this->image);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

     imagepng($this->image);
  }
}
function getWidth() {

  return imagesx($this->image);
}
 function getHeight() {

  return imagesy($this->image);
}
function resizeToHeight($height) {

  $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
  $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
  $this->resize($width,$height);
}
function resizeToWidth($width) {
  $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
  $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
  $this->resize($width,$height);
}
function scale($scale) {
  $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
  $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
  $this->resize($width,$height);
}
function resize($width,$height) {
  $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
   imagecopyresampled($new_image,$this->image,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$this->getWidth(),$this->getHeight());
  $this->image = $new_image;
}      

}

?>
```

And my php code looks like..

```
include_once(ROOT.'/library/SimpleImage.php')
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load($image_name);
$image->resizeToWidth(100);
$image->save($image_name);
```

Now the problem is that my images are getting compressed, but their original color combination get lost...
Don't know what to do..??

Please suggest another class for image compression.

Comment: What do you mean with color combination? What image are you trying to convert? (jpg/png?)

Comment: Do you need to handle all image formats or can you just use jpeg compression?

Comment: Compression and resizing are not the same. Which one do you want?

Comment: I want to handle all type of images...
And i want to resize the image as well as compress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function I coded a long time ago, it's not realy optimized but it should do the trick. Works for various mime types and allows you to save the modified image into a new location. You can easily simplify it if you need less features.

```
public function resizePicture($path, $new_path, $new_width, $new_height, $proportion = false) {
    $size = getimagesize($path);
    $x = 0;
    $y = 0;

    switch($size['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $picture = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
        break;
        case 'image/png':
            $picture = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $picture = imagecreatefromgif($path);
        break;
        default:
            return false;
        break;
    }

    $width = $size[0];
    $height = $size[1];

    $frame = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    if($size['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $bg = imagecolorallocate($frame, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefill($frame, 0, 0, $bg);
    } else if($size['mime'] == 'image/gif' or $size['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        imagealphablending($picture, false);
        imagesavealpha($picture, true);
        imagealphablending($frame, false);
        imagesavealpha($frame, true);
    }

    if($width < $new_width and $height < $new_height) {
        $x = ($new_width - $width) / 2;
        $y = ($new_height - $height) / 2;
        imagecopy($frame, $picture, $x, $y, 0, 0, $width, $height);
    } else {
        if($proportion and $width != $height) {
            if($width > $height) {
                $old_height = $new_height;
                $new_height = $height * $new_width / $width;
                $y = abs($old_height - $new_height) / 2;
            } else {
                $old_width = $new_width;
                $new_width = $width * $new_height / $height;
                $x = abs($old_width - $new_width) / 2;
            }
        }
        imagecopyresampled($frame, $picture, $x, $y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    }

    switch($size['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            imagejpeg($frame, $new_path, 85);
        break;
        case 'image/png':
            imagepng($frame, $new_path, 8);
        break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($frame, $new_path);
        break;
        default:
            return false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Ronan this is working..
But some images are not getting resize...
And also back ground of some images are also getting change...

Can you please short out the problem..

Thanks...

Comment: In which case do you experience those problems? (original image size / new image size / mime type, etc..)

Comment: @Ronan is ur script usefull for just compress image size. i dont want to resize image just need to compress kb.

Answer (score 0):

I use SimpleImage.php and find it a helpful little script, but I had to change the value of $compression to 100 in save function.

Perhaps compressing certain formats reduces number of colors, but by setting $compression to a 100 you tell the script "Don't compress!"
After that the images look like they suppose to.